# Dynamic mean in r

Tags: r, date, dataframe, mean, country

I have this data frame:

```
      RANKING.Country.or.Area   Year   Average..last.5.years.   GDP     
 1              Afghanistan     1970                        629.0927   
 2              Afghanistan     1971                        610.3037      
 3              Afghanistan     1972                        496.1446        
 4              Afghanistan     1973                        496.7760          
 5              Afghanistan     1974      mean(1970:1974)   510.7517             
 6              Afghanistan     1975      mean(1971:1975)   530.4223               
 7              Afghanistan     1976      mean(1972:1976)   548.2869                        
 8              Afghanistan     1977      mean(1973:1977)   511.5458                  
 9              Afghanistan     1978      mean(1974:1978)   542.5502                      
 10             Afghanistan     1979      mean(1975:1979)   526.2770
 11             Afghanistan     1980      mean(1976:1980)   509.6642
 12             Afghanistan     1981      mean(1977:1981)   529.3375
```

The related time series is 1970:2014 and it contains about 9000 rows for 187 Countries.

I should find a way in r to calculate - in the column "Average..last.5.years." - the 'dynamic'  mean of GDP over the last 5 years, considering any year and any Country variation (i.e. for 1975, the mean 1971:1975; for 1990, the mean 1986:1990 and so on).

Comment: By "dynamic", you mean "rolling"?

Comment: You can use `rollmean` from `library(zoo)`  Please show at least 10 rows and the expected output based on that.